# PySpark adding values to one DataFrame based on columns of 2nd DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two PySpark DataFrames like the following:

DataFrame A:

```
+-----+------+
|nodes|counts|
+-----+------+
|  [0]|     1|
|  [1]|     0|
|  [2]|     1|
|  [3]|     0|
|  [4]|     0|
|  [5]|     0|
|  [6]|     1|
|  [7]|     0|
|  [8]|     0|
|  [9]|     0|
| [10]|     0|
```

And DataFrame B:

```
+----+------+
|nodes|counts|
+----+------+
|[0] |     1|
|[1] |     0|
|[2] |     3|
|[6] |     0|
|[8] |     2|
+----+------+
```

I would like  create a new DataFrame C such that  values in the "counts" column in DataFrame A are summed with the values in the "counts" column of DataFrame B where the "nodes" columns are equal such that DataFrame C looks like:

```
+-----+------+
|nodes|counts|
+-----+------+
|  [0]|     2|
|  [1]|     0|
|  [2]|     4|
|  [3]|     0|
|  [4]|     0|
|  [5]|     0|
|  [6]|     1|
|  [7]|     0|
|  [8]|     2|
|  [9]|     0|
| [10]|     0|
```

I appreciate the help!  I've tried a few different tricks using lambda functions and sql statements and am coming up short on a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a more efficient way, but this should work:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

dfA = spark.createDataFrame([([0], 1),([1], 0),([2], 1),([3], 0), ([4], 0),([5], 0),([6], 1),([7], 0), ([8], 0),([9], 0),([10], 0)], ["nodes", "counts"])
dfB = spark.createDataFrame([([0], 1),([1], 0),([2], 3),([6], 0), ([8], 2)], ["nodes", "counts"])

dfC = dfA.join(dfB, dfA.nodes == dfB.nodes, "left")\
    .withColumn("sum",func.when(dfB.nodes.isNull(), dfA.counts).otherwise(dfA.counts+ dfB.counts))\
    .select(dfA.nodes.alias("nodes"), func.col("sum").alias("counts"))

dfC.orderBy("nodes").show()
+-----+------+
|nodes|counts|
+-----+------+
|  [0]|     2|
|  [1]|     0|
|  [2]|     4|
|  [3]|     0|
|  [4]|     0|
|  [5]|     0|
|  [6]|     1|
|  [7]|     0|
|  [8]|     2|
|  [9]|     0|
| [10]|     0|
+-----+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `join` this two dataframe as below and replace `null` with `0` and add two column to get the `sum`

```
A.join(B.withColumnRenamed("count", "countB"), Seq("nodes"), "left")
  .na.fill(0)
  .withColumn("count", $"count" + $"countB")
  .drop("countB")
  .show(false)
```

You can also merge those dataframe in single using `union` and then groupBy nodes and calculate the `sum` as below

```
A.union(B).groupBy("nodes").agg(sum($"count").alias("count"))
  .orderBy("nodes")
  .show(false)
```

This is in scala hope you can write it in pyspark.

Hope this helps!